# Qt, printing a QDialog in PDF format, quality issues

Tags: qt, pdf, printing, qprinter

I have some problems using QPdfWriter and QPainter to print a part of a QDialog.

To contextualize a bit, I'm working as Engineer in a Telemetry/LiDAR company, and for internal use I have developed a GUI for easily compare/simulate our systems. I have no computer formation so I developed it only after following some Qt tutorials etc (I like coding in general, but I mean I am not that goood at it).

In this GUI I have incorporated an "overview". In practice, it summarize all the inputs and outputs, in a QDialog. This QDialog contains a scrollArea, defined at the centralWidget. (screen right there : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pIbw.jpg )

So my researches make me use this kind of coding to grab the scrollArea, and to print it in PDF :

```
QString filePath=QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "System summary",path,"PDF files (*.pdf)");

QPdfWriter pdfWriter(filePath);
pdfWriter.setResolution(100);
QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&pdfWriter);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform);
QPixmap screenshotPDF = contenu->QWidget::grab();
painter.drawPixmap(0,0,screenshotPDF);

painter.end();
```

In case of, the content of the screen area is completely manually made (It has the dimension of an A4 paper, and I put the QGroupBox without layout).

Thing is the result doesn't have a good quality. I tried to play on the renderHint, on the resolution, but I don't find something quite good.
screen here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWUPc.jpg. As you can see, it's "blurry" and not neat.

I guess I'm doing something wrong, but all that I try didn't work really well (for example, if I just change the "setResolution" line to N*100, I end up with something N time too small/High)

That's the first time I post here, I hope my question is appropriate, also I wanted to thank you for this forum which help a lot the neophyte I am.

Imra'